# firebase is not accepting value from $scope

Tags: angularjs, scope, firebase

I am using firebase and plain angularjs. When i tried to get some value from the $scope and set it as a checking parameter it is not working and throwing the error

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error: Firebase.DataSnapshot.hasChild failed: First argument was an invalid path: "234". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
at Error (native)
at Xf (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js:133:59)
at S.Ha (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js:197:315)
at http://localhost/sriram/Copy%20of%2004-05-2016/js/app.js:75:23
at c (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js:227:65)
at https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js:49:642
at Cb (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js:46:165)
at yb (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js:22:216)
at zb (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js:21:1259)
at Kh.h.Gb (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js:203:287) 
firebase.js:133 Uncaught Error: Firebase.DataSnapshot.hasChild failed: First argument was an invalid path: "234". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
```

My Code :

```
$scope.signIn = function()  {
    var primarynumber = $scope.primary_number;
    signInrefTwo = signInref.push();
    console.log($scope.signin_name);
    users = signInref;
      var username =primarynumber;
    users.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasChild(username)) {
        users.child(username).set({ name: username });
    }
        else {
        alert("That user already exists");
        }
    });


    console.log();

}
```

My working COde :

```
 $scope.signIn = function()  {
    var primarynumber = '123456789';
    signInrefTwo = signInref.push();
    console.log($scope.signin_name);
```

May i know the reason for this. I tried to console the $scope.primary_number and it is returning value correctly.

Comment: Is the value you are passing in the .child() function a string or something else like a number?

Comment: @AndréKool : Yup. Got it working. Actually forgot to add .toString() to it. its passing as object in it.

Answer (score 0):

we have to add .toString() to the var that you are assigning

```
var username = primarynumber.toString(); // it has to be done all the time
```